Using Allstar's web transceiver function
I am trying to connect to a repeater with Allstar but this is what I get:

There is nothing underneath the label. I read a PDF that says you needed to use a browser that supports Java, so I went with Pale Moon, but it just says the security features are too strict, even though I set an exception for Allstar. So I tried a lot of other things like using Opera One but I couldn't find the setting for Java on it. I also emailed Allstar about it, but this is what I got back:

He said I should use Tranceive on MacOS, but I'm not paying 20$ for a piece of software. I'm pretty sure at least one of you have accessed a repeater before using Allstar, so could you tell me your process?

why didn't you ask on the linked community site?

Java in the browser ("Java Applets") have been deprecated since at least 2009, and since latest 2017, no browser supports them anymore (and that's not something that was disabled. The interfaces for these are just gone.).
So, whatever this is, if it relies on Java in the browser, it's dead as a doornail.
However, my suspicion is that your PDF is simply obsolete, as the official website (allstarlink.org), which is the only authorative resource, I'd say, makes absolutely no mention of it.
So, your problem is that you've got a website and it doesn't work. I'm afraid nobody can really help you but the administrator of the server you're connecting to.
